Trying to understand how to search a BST with a given input
I am trying to figure out how to search a BST via a given input. The nodes in the tree have a randomly generated number as the key, and the value of the node is an object with various attributes.
Searching the BST via the key is simple enough, as the algorithm can decide to go left/right depending on the current and given key. But searching via an attribute seems impossible to me without making the process 'linear' (iterating through all the nodes and returning ones with matching attributes, wouldn't that defeat the purpose of a binary search tree?).
TL;DR How should I go about searching the title 'A Book' for example? I can't seem to discern the approach I should be taking.
import random


class Item:
    def __init__(self, title, category, language, authors, year_published):
        self.title = title
        self.category = category
        self.language = language
        self.authors = authors
        self.year_published = year_published
        self.id = random.randint(100000, 999999)

class Node:

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = item.id
        self.value = item

    def insert(self, item):
        if item.id < self.key:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(item)
                self.left.value = item
            else:
                self.left.insert(item)

        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(item)
                self.right.value = item
            else:
                self.right.insert(item)

    def find(self, key):
        if key < self.key:
            if self.left is None:
                return None
            else:
                return self.left.find(key)

        elif key > self.key:
            if self.right is None:
                return None
            else:
                return self.right.find(key)
        else:
            return self

def main():

    metamorphosis = Item("Metamorphosis", "Novel", 'English', 'Franz Kafka',
                         1915)

    a_book = Item("A Book", "Biography", 'English', 'Someone',
                 2024)

    journal = Item("A Journal", "Fiction", 'Various', 'Author',
                 2001)

    library_tree = Node(metamorphosis)

    library_tree.insert(a_book)
    library_tree.insert(journal)

    # i want to do this
    library_tree.search_title("A Book")


A BST is meant to be searched efficiently for the key only. You would have to create additional BSTs (or similar data structures) for other independent criteria (like the title) you want to search for.

I believe this problem lacks serious context and details: why are you using a BST when there is no clear-cut explicit relationship between the keys you're using to rank the values? Once you are able to answer that, you will perhaps build a different data structure and perform your search differently.

Perhaps, you should favor indexing the book items with a rank key that sorts the book titles in alphabetic order. Then your search becomes efficient in a BST. But again, isn't an ordinary hash table more ideal for this?

@M.A. My algorithms & data structures assignment requires me to utilize a BST to store all the items a library has on offer, and to be able to insert/delete items in addition to searching items via the title, category, language etc. In my first iteration of the tree, I actually used the titles as the key - but felt that a random integer would be better as there could be books with the same titles.

@rgs: Don't use a random integer, come up with a definite integer, i.e. a hashed value (with a strong hash function, provided (or preferably if) your alphabet domain for book titles is a closed set). This way, we know exactly which direction to head during the search.

"My algorithms & data structures assignment requires me...": please quote the assignment literally, so we can assess what exactly is expected. A BST based on a random key provides no search advantages.

@rgs I've extended my solution with an alternative that achieves O(1) time hashing thus, maintaining logarithmic lookup time for your query by book title.

I don't recommend using a BST for this problem. But if you must search with the book title, then you need a strong hash function to represent the string in integral form, while creating an exclusive association between each title and the corresponding hashed value.
The Case for Strong Hashing
I have utilized Fowler–Noll–Vo (FNV) hash here just for demonstration, but you should ideally choose a faster one that comes close to O(1) time complexity (as ultimately explained herewith).
To effect these changes, we have to update your entire code structure by standardizing the Node class, and creating a separate BST class to deputize your tree structure without mixing code unnecessarily.
Node class
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = self.fnv_hash32(item.title.encode('utf-8'))
        self.value = item

    @staticmethod
    def fnv_hash32(data: bytes) -> int:
        FNV_prime = 16777619
        offset_basis = 2166136261
        hash_value = offset_basis
        for byte in data:
            hash_value = hash_value * FNV_prime
            hash_value = hash_value ^ byte
            hash_value = hash_value & 0xFFFFFFFF  # Ensure it's a 32-bit hash
        return hash_value

BST class
class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self._root = None
        self._size = 0

    def root(self):
        return self._root

    def search_title(self, title):
        return self._search(Node.fnv_hash32(title.encode('utf-8')), self._root)

    def insert(self, item: Item, node: Node, ik=None):
        if self._size == 0:
            self._root = Node(item)
        else:
            if node:
                item_key = ik if ik else Node.fnv_hash32(item.title.encode('utf-8'))
                if node.key == item_key:
                    return  # Item already exists in BST
                else:
                    if item_key < node.key:
                        if node.left:
                            return self.insert(item, node.left, item_key)
                        else:
                            node.left = Node(item)
                    else:  # item_key > node.key
                        if node.right:
                            return self.insert(item, node.right, item_key)
                        else:
                            node.right = Node(item)
        self._size += 1
        return

    def _search(self, key, node: Node):
        if node:
            print(f"query key = {key}\ncurrent search key = {node.key}")
            if node.key == key:
                return node  # Successful search
            else:
                if key < node.key:
                    return self._search(key, node.left)
                else:  # key > node.key
                    return self._search(key, node.right)
        return None  # Unsuccessful search

main() function
def main():
    metamorphosis = Item("Metamorphosis",
                         "Novel",
                         'English',
                         'Franz Kafka',
                         1915)

    a_book = Item("A Book",
                  "Biography",
                  'English',
                  'Someone',
                  2024)

    journal = Item("A Journal",
                   "Fiction",
                   'Various',
                   'Author',
                   2001)

    library_tree = BST()
    library_tree.insert(metamorphosis, library_tree.root())
    library_tree.insert(a_book, library_tree.root())
    library_tree.insert(journal, library_tree.root())

    for b in metamorphosis, a_book, journal:
        query = library_tree.search_title(b.title)
        if query: print(vars(query.value), "\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Output
query key = 1101194702
current search key = 1101194702
{'title': 'Metamorphosis', 'category': 'Novel', 'language': 'English', 'authors': 'Franz Kafka', 'year_published': 1915, 'id': 597163} 

query key = 284719185
current search key = 1101194702
query key = 284719185
current search key = 284719185
{'title': 'A Book', 'category': 'Biography', 'language': 'English', 'authors': 'Someone', 'year_published': 2024, 'id': 455289} 

query key = 2436376883
current search key = 1101194702
query key = 2436376883
current search key = 2436376883
{'title': 'A Journal', 'category': 'Fiction', 'language': 'Various', 'authors': 'Author', 'year_published': 2001, 'id': 884345} 

Towards O(1) Time Hashing
In Python, strings are immutable objects, and the language uses a technique called interning to optimize memory usage and improve performance. This ensures storing only one copy of each distinct string value, which is then shared among all variables that have the same value. This S.O. post is a great place to start for understanding the basics of string interning in Python.
From the Python docs:

id(Object)
Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

This means we can take advantage of the inbuilt id() function by simply taking down the memory address of the book title string/search query, and then hash it using the default hash() function to effectuate stronger uniqueness. The threshold for all operations involved is O(1).
Updated Node class
class Node:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        . = ((.))
        self.value = item

Updated search_title() and insert() methods of BST class
def search_title(self, title):
    return self._search((()), self._root)

def insert(self, item: Item, node: Node, ik=None):
    if self._size == 0:
        self._root = Node(item)
    else:
        if node:
            _ =     ((.))
            if node.key == item_key:
                return  # Item already exists in BST
            else:
                if item_key < node.key:
                    if node.left:
                        return self.insert(item, node.left, item_key)
                    else:
                        node.left = Node(item)
                else:  # item_key > node.key
                    if node.right:
                        return self.insert(item, node.right, item_key)
                    else:
                        node.right = Node(item)
    self._size += 1
    return

The main function remains unchanged and produces the same correct output as discussed earlier. Even querying the search method without using the title attribute of an existing book Item, i.e. calling library_tree.search_title("Metamorphosis") for example, also correctly returns a valid result.
Further Reading
If you want to implement a proper deletion method (or balancing, or any other common BST utilities), please see Section 11.1.4 of Goodrich, Tamassia & Goldwasser (2013). My code borrows the structure and format of their BST implementation. Goodrich et. al also used memory address-oriented hashing for mapping incident vertices and edges of a graph in Section 14.2.5.
